# Does CH3CHNH exist, and what is it called?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, lewis-structure

I am drawing different Lewis Structures of small compounds containing nitrogen, hydrogen, and carbon. One permutation is $\ce{CH_3CHNH}$, but I have never heard of this compound. Initially, and falsely, I thought this compound was acetonitrile. It isn't coming up in Wolfram Alpha, Pubchem, or Wikipedia.

Does this compound exist? Also, what would this compound be called regardless of its existence value?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethanimine

Comment: @Loong I found that searching 'CH3CHNH' did not get me anything, but Ethanimine does appear to be the right compound name for 'CH3CHNH'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The -CH=NH functional group is called an imine (in this case a primary imine) your molecule would be called *Ethan-1-imine*

Comment: A.K. all your answers are one liners that, while a good answer somewhere like Yahoo answers, don't comply to our standards. Please refrain from posting such answers, as the goal here isn't quick answers, it's **high-quality content**.

Comment: The question was also about existance - this compound is **very** reactive.

Comment: I would like to see more information on the existence of the compound. I think @A.K. sufficiently answered the nomenclature part of the question.

Comment: It doesn't ocurr terrestrially as it is very reactive, but it can form in space.
 Per Loong: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethanimine

Comment: @Galen imines typically hydrolise very fast, unless stabilized by bulky substituents and $\pi$ conjugation. Typical example of stabilized imines are Schiff bases, oxyms, hydrazones, iminoesters and varios compounds with imine group included in aromatic system. like pyridine.